# How to update Zookeeper(as Configuration Management) with the configurations for the current revision of the application in startup time

Tags: spring-boot, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I am using Zookeeper as configuration management for my application which is designed in microservices architecture and implemented with spring-boot. My configurations will originally be in the application source control(git), so that I can keep track of changes in configurations as well as being able to deploy any version of the application easily. Now I need a tool to apply changes in configurations (of the current revision) to the Zookeeper server so that all the instances of application can rely on the Zookeeper server and pick up the changes in the configuration at runtime. Are there any tools or practices (maven plug-in, script, library ...) to apply changes to zookeeper server?